# How can be changed a documenttype layout in Hippo CMS

Tags: hippocms

I created a hippo documenttype using a one column layout. For rendering purposes I would like to reorganize the given items into a two-columns layout.

However, no option is available to do this change, at least not by using the latest hippo cms community version.

I have already searched in google and found following information, saying that it may be possible to change the layout by using the console, but no information about how:

http://hippo.2275632.n2.nabble.com/How-to-delete-or-rename-document-types-td7579269.html

I would appreciate any hints about it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no documentation on how to do this: this is not very complicated but this is a tedious process. If you still can - for instance your document type is not used yet - I would advise to simply drop it and recreate the content type. That being said, here is how it works:

- look into your project namespace in the console: the path is something like this: */hippo:namespaces/YOURPROJECT/document-type/editor:templates/_default_/root*
- the root nodes defines the layout. Check out the **plugin.class**: for a one column this will be *org.hippoecm.frontend.service.render.ListViewPlugin* and for a 2 column layout the **plugin.class** will be *org.hippoecm.frontend.editor.layout.TwoColumn*
- for every field in your document type (that's the tedious part) you will need to define if the field placed on the right or the left.
- this is configured on the node with the name of the field path, as a property **wicket.id** that for instance have the value *${cluster.id}.left.item*. This means the item will be placed on the left side.

Your best bet is to create a 2 column example document type and look carefully at its configuration and replicate the changes in your existing field.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the instructions on the link below ? 
http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/document-types/custom-editor-layout.html